# How to change anchor point in text in Raphael?

Tags: raphael

This is difficult to explain, but I'm creating text via:

```
txt = paper.text(10, fontSize / 2 + 10, 'YOUR NAME').attr({
    'fill': '#fff',
    'font-size': fontSize + 'px',
    'font-family': 'Impact',
    'text-anchor': 'start'
});
```

And then animating it:

```
txt.animate({transform: 's0.3'}, 1000);
```

And the text shrinks around a center anchor point. Is there some way to get it to scale down and maintain the same X position (left anchor)?

Answer (score 3):

Found it. There are optional coordinate parameters for 's' to specify origin point. This fixes it:

```
txt.animate({transform: 's0.3,0.3,0,0'}, 1000);
```

Params for scale: s[SCALEX],[SCALEY],[ORIGINX],[ORIGINY]